# Parent job monitoring Children jobs in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Is there a plugin or a way for a parent job to monitor children jobs in Jenkins.

I looked at multi-configuration and matrix jobs, but cannot find a way to do this.

I need a parent job which gets triggered and starts children jobs and monitors the child jobs till completion and the status of the parent job is pass or fail based on the status of the child jobs.

```
Parent job pass: All children have completed successfully.

Parent job fail: even one child job has a failure.
```